# How to get Test Step Action / Expected Result Descriptions from API Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to get the test step Action and Expected Result Descriptions for the test steps of a specific test case. Is there any way to obtain this information with API call?

[image: The red parts are descriptions, which I want]

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/action%20results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I edited my post to show what information I wanted. I tried that API call and it does not have the descriptions of the Expected Result or Action for a test step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it through calling work item api.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

It will be in MSFT.System.Steps field